# view word documents in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

this my program to view file word  document ,choosing the file from  FileDialog  when running the program don't show any thing ,  I adding the DocX as reference ,what is the error in it?

```
<Window x:Class="Wordviewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="524" Width="901">
<Grid Background="#FF464966">
    <DocumentViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,0"
                Name="documentViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="508" Width="923" BorderBrush="#FFA28D8D" />
    <TextBox Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0"
         Name="FileNameTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="730" TextChanged="SelectedFileTextBox_TextChanged" />
    <Button Content="Browse" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="757,6,0,0"
        Name="BrowseButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Click="BrowseButton_Click" FontWeight="Bold">
        <Button.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFD0BDBD" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.BorderBrush>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

and this

```
  private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create OpenFileDialog 
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".doc";
        dlg.Filter = "Word documents|*.doc;*.docx";

        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;

            var document = DocX.Load(filename);

            string contents = document.Text;

            // Use the file
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try to look here, it may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649064/Show-Word-File-in-WPF

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't. The `DocumentViewer` control in WPF cannot display Word document files (`.doc`, `.docx`). It's meant to display XPS files which is a conceptually different kind of document similar to PDFs.

(For the uninitiated, Word documents are different from PDF and XPS documents (despite looking the same when printed) in that they're editable, reflow-able, structured-ish documents, whereas PDF and XPS documents essentially just tell a printer what to print (like PostScript) - think of it as comparing a vector drawing to a raster image, even though they can both look the same.)

There are ways around this, they all involve converting the Word document to XPS. The first route is to use Office Automation to load Word in-process and convert the document to XPS, this requires that Word be installed and available on the system. The second option is to use a third-party library like Aspose or Gem.

Comment: thank's ,I programming small program that viewing word and save it as xps,don't found any way to viewing only view the word

Comment: Here is an example of this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSVSTOViewWordInWPF-db347436

Answer (score 0):

You actually have one option, you could use the Office Interop Libraries, open the Word Document with these, then save them as XPS and then you can view it. But I think that is a bit to heavy.

Check this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/word